# Qestion about JQuery and If/else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, border

I am trying to do condition, that checks if my 8 classes are same border color, it executes something.

For example this:

```
var alt = $(".test").css;
var altt = $(".test").css("border", "5px solid green");

if (alt == altt) {alert()}
```

Just colors all borders green and doesnt pop up alert

I also tried a lot of different variants of this and it just usually makes syntax error or something else, but nothing works.. I also searched about this question but couldn't find anything that would help me.

I am very inexperienced with jQuery, but I really need to get this working.

Thanks

Comment: first one returns a function not an actual css value .... those 2 variables will never match. Please explain in words what you are trying to do

Comment: I want it to check if all my class .test elements has same border, and if it does it does soemting, for example `alert()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for can be done using this code:

```
if( $('.test').css('border') == '1px solid rgb(0, 128, 0)' ) alert(1);
```

Note that `.css()` always returns colors as RGB values. If you need to use HEX values, consider conversions. You can find some samples here: [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: Thanks. I tryed same thing but used not rgb but `green`